# Extremely slow speed when writing to USB FAT32 drive in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, performance

I'm trying to copy around 4GB of files onto a USB 3.0 drive formatted with FAT32. The speed is ridiculously slow - 200 kBytes/sec. Writing data directly with `dd` is okay at about 25-30 MBytes/sec, and writing the same data on an ext4 partition on the same device is going at 9-10MBytes/sec. I am running Arch Linux at 4.1.2 kernel. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem, as it turns out, was the sync option used to mount the filesystem, which appears to be performance-killer. Mounting it with `flush` option instead of `sync` solved the problem:
`sudo mount -o async,flush <device> <mountpoint>`

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: By the way, how did you figure out that sync option was the performance-killer ?